# How to swap the first two characters of each element in a pd Series?

Tags: python, series, swap

I have a series, `A = (3223, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 2323, 3323, 2449, NaN)`. I want two swap the first 2 characters of each element in the series, so `A = (2323, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 3223, 3323, 4249, NaN)`. How can I do this?

Comment: Is your series a Pandas series? And are the numbers in the series strings?

Answer (score 2):

```
A = [1234, 5678, 9112, 9243]

# Iterate over the elements in the list
for i, x in enumerate(A):
    # Check if the current element is a string
    if isinstance(x, str):
        # Extract the first two characters from the string
        first_two_chars = x[:2]
        # Extract the rest of the string (after the first two characters)
        rest_of_string = x[2:]
        # Reverse the order of the first two characters
        reversed_first_two_chars = first_two_chars[::-1]
        # Concatenate the reversed first two characters with the rest of the string
        new_string = reversed_first_two_chars + rest_of_string
        # Assign the new string to the original element in the list
        A[i] = new_string

# The list A should now contain the swapped elements
print(A)

0    2134
1    6578
2    1912
3    2943
```

Comment: This swaps the first 2 digits with the next 2 digits. Whereas, I want to do the swapping in the first 2 digits only. So A = [1234, 5678, 9112, 9243] after the swapping operation should be A = [2134, 6578, 1912, 2943].

Comment: @wowzer I think I misunderstood your question. Check my edit now, hope this time it's what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

List comprehension is useful here:

```
[str(x)[:2][::-1]+str(x)[2:] if !np.isnan(x) else x for x in A]
```

Answer (score 0):

Given, your pd.Series has dtype of object (or strings) like this:

```
A = pd.Series(['3223'] + [np.nan]*4 + ['2323', '3323', '2449', np.nan])
```

You can use .str acceess with some slicing to achieve your results,

```
A.str[:2].str[::-1]+A.str[2:]
```

Output:

```
0    2323
1     NaN
2     NaN
3     NaN
4     NaN
5    3223
6    3323
7    4249
8     NaN
dtype: object
```